# How "this" reference binds respect to arrow notation?

Tags: javascript, this

I'm struggling with "this" keyword in JS.
I've listed 3 different cases that I'm confusing with.

```
const person = {
    name: "joe",
    talk(){
        this.foo(function (){
            console.log(this);
        });
    },
    foo(a) {
        a()
    }
};
person.talk();
```

In the first scenario: despite foo is a member of person object; when I call foo function it returns me a window object reference.

```
const person = {
    name: "joe",
    talk(){
        foo(function (){
            console.log(this);
        });
    },

};

function foo(a){
    a()
}
person.talk();
```

In the second scenario: there is nothing changed, though I put foo function outside of person object.

But if I change the way of defining the callback function within foo function with Arrow notation as follows:

```
const person = {
    name: "joe",
    talk(){
        foo(() => {
            console.log(this);
        });
    },

};

function foo(a){
    a()
}
person.talk();
```

Then this time, the first scenario and the second scenario that I mentioned above print out the reference of person object regardless whether foo is defined within person object or not.

What is the basis of those results?

Comment: `this` in arrow function is the same `this` when you create the function

Comment: The use of `this` in an arrow function does not cause `this` to be altered. It therefore points to whatever it did just prior to the arrow function invocation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I recommend checking out the [MDN `this` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) which does quite a good job of explaining `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to shamelessly copy-paste https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp here:

> In regular functions the this keyword represented the object that
> called the function, which could be the window, the document, a button
> or whatever.
>
> With arrow functions the this keyword always represents the object
> that defined the arrow function.

### To elaborate further on your scenarios:

#### Regular function

```
const person = {
    name: "joe",
    talk(){
        this.foo(function (){
            console.log(this);
        });
    },
    foo(a) {
        a()
    }
};
person.talk();
```

and

```
const person = {
    name: "joe",
    talk(){
        foo(function (){
            console.log(this);
        });
    },

};

function foo(a){
    a()
}
person.talk();
```

this == the object calling the sequence of function == window

#### Arrow function

```
const person = {
    name: "joe",
    talk(){
        this.foo(() => {
            console.log(this);
        });
    },
    foo(a) {
        a()
    }
};
person.talk();
```

and

```
const person = {
    name: "joe",
    talk(){
        foo(() => {
            console.log(this);
        });
    },

};

function foo(a){
    a()
}
person.talk();
```

this == the object that defines the function == person

#### Bonus: which one to use

Quoted from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/:

> ES6 arrow functions can’t be bound to a this keyword, so it will
> lexically go up a scope, and use the value of this in the scope in
> which it was defined.

If you are familiar with `Fn.bind()`, it's a known trick to change what a regular function refers to as `this`. An arrow function does not follow this trick and always stick to the `this` that refers to its parent scope.

Especially if you are developing a library for others to use, use an arrow function if you want to be confident on using `this` to refer to its parent scope. Use a regular function for event handling since `this` will refer to the event source (button, text field etc). If you must use a regular function and must refer to its parent scope, use [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) to freeze the parent scope instead of using `this`.